# MVC5 DataAnnotations for formatting and decorating numbers in razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC5 and creating a Model and View that displays user editable values in Textbox controls. I see the `[DisplayFormat()]` and `[DataType()]` annotations, but I'm not sure how either/both of these will allow including a percent sign in a textbox control automatically. For example, I'm looking for a desired display of:

```
+-----------+
|       -2% |
+-----------+
```

So if the user enters the textbox and types a value of only `2` the textbox will display 2% automatically. If the user were to type a value of `-2` the textbox will display -2% automatically.

I also need one textbox control to display a `+` plus sign for positive values and a `-` minus sign that can be specified by the user to make the value negative. So if the user enters `2` in the textbox it will display as +2 but if they specify `-2` it will display as -2 accordingly. A little trickier...

If it is possible to annotate Model class members to meet this requirement, how are these fields handled in the POST Controller Action? In other words, will I have to strip the percent sign from the value or is it not included?

I understand this is masking and I am aware of jQuery extensions/plugins that will do this, but I can't determine if this is a format/mask that can be specified in the Model without the need for jQuery.

I have some other special requirements, but I think the answer to this will point me in the direction I need to be. Does anyone have an example snippet of how to decorate a Model member and display it in a razor View?

Comment: If your project is using Bootstrap, I would suggest using input groups and have the % sign outside the box http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: I am using Bootstrap. I didn't think about this ability. It's not a complete solution, but might help out. Are you saying there isn't a way of decorating the Model to accommodate my needs? The field will need to look like it's all one but I suppose that's just CSS to clear background color and borders. I was hoping there was a way of using a DataAnnotation in the Model. Thanks DavidG.

Comment: Personally I hate when an input has % sign, currency symbols etc. in with the textbox, but I don't know you solution. It can be done your way but it seems awkward.

Comment: I agree with you. In this case I don't have a choice since I didn't design the UI - my job is to code it accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor don't use server controls (as aspx with codebehind did).

This means you are limited(?) to use HTML controls and you can't avoid using javascript if you want a special behavior.

I suggest the following jQuery [plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: I kind of expected this might be the case. I will take a look at the link you provided. Thanks for that.